# Best way to integrate NodeJS with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to make a web application that uses a Node server as the back end and Angular to take information from the Node server and create a responsive front end. Currently, in my simple application, I have two js files: `server.js` and `controller.js`. Here is the code for each file:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var port = 8006;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());         
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post('/data', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Success!")
    res.status(200);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on port " + port);
```

And here's the controller file:

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

   var TileController = function($scope){
       // add stuff to $scope as initilization        
   };

   app.controller("TileController", ["$scope", TileController]);    
})();
```

This code is sort of incomplete because I'm not sure where to go with it, but I know what I want to do with it.

The model that Angular uses is going to be constantly updated by information parsed by the Node server upon incoming HTTP requests (specifically POST). Node is going to handle these requests and somehow pass the data along to Angular (in the controller.js file), which is going to update the model, and update the view along with that.

My question is what is the best way to pass information along from the Node server to the controller.js and update the model/view when the information is added?

Comment: What you're asking for is real-time capabilities (automatically update angular scope when node receives data). Before that, I suggest trying to accomplish the same task but not in real-time. (e.g. have a button in angular that does a GET for latest data from node).

Comment: So you're saying that angular should be making requests to the node server?

Comment: From there, the naive but simple way to accomplish (almost) real-time sync is to remove the button in angular but make angular GET data from node every X seconds, infinitely.

Comment: In the real world, this would be accomplished using either HTTP long-polling or Websockets, the latter being more modern. These are more complicated, so I suggest trying them after simple HTTP requests.

Comment: Yep, use an angular service to make the HTTP requests and call the service in your controller

Comment: I'm interested in this websocket idea, because ultimately I want to be polling for information constantly from node. However, I've had trouble in the past with updating the view after updating angular's model. What's the best way to do this/.

Comment: In that case, check out http://socket.io. This abstracts away the low-level details of websockets and makes it easier to get started with.

Comment: I'm still confused about what sockets.io does. Why can't I go directly from node to angular? Do I need sockets.io as a middle man?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94769/discussion-between-scotty-pippen-and-prashanth-chandra).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a very simple example using just HTTP requests, and `$interval`, which is angular's equivalent of `window.setInterval`.

- Save all the files in a folder
- Download the node modules (express, body-parser)
- `node server.js`
- open index.html
- POST some data to server (http://localhost:3000)
- index.html should show a list of every data that was POST'd to the server, delayed by ~3 seconds

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var arr  = [];

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({arr: arr});
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  arr.push(req.body);
  res.end('Data received');
})

app.listen(3000, console.log.call(console, 'Server started.'));
```

**app.js (angular)**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval, $http) {
  $scope.arr = [];
  var stop = $interval(function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000')
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.arr = res.data.arr;
      }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }, 3000);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta content="UTF-8">
  <title>live data example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in arr">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Awww, very clever. I'll have to try this out :)

Comment: Hey, if you're satisfied with the answer, don't forget to accept and close :)